# See errors, warnings, and suggestions in Error List for Unity projects in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Starting up a new Unity game project, and using Visual Studio 2019 Community (VS) for my C# development. Unity shows errors in the console window but I find that limiting and inconvenient. I would like to enable all errors, warnings, and suggestions in Visual Studio itself.

I have "Disable the full build of projects" set to false in VS (in the "Tools for Unity" Options tab). I have my error list dropdown set to "Build + Intellisense". Changing any of those flags doesn't seem to do much of anything. I am using Visual Studio 2019 and Unity 2020.2.4f1. I don't see a csproj file or any other project files in VS or Unity or my Windows Explorer. It appears to build because I can play in the Unity editor.

Is it possible to show the errors in VS's Error List window with Unity projects or not? How do I set it up to show errors in VS for Unity projects?

EDIT: One more thing, I am unable to see Intellisense suggestions at all for my project as I write code in VS so it makes coding that much slower and inaccurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer on a different site than StackOverflow and verified it this morning.

1. In Unity, go to *Edit->Preferences->External Tools*.
2. Change the *External Script Editor* to your instance of Visual Studio.
3. In the new options below for *Generate .csproj files for:*, make sure *Embedded packages* and *Local Packages* are selected.
4. Click the button *Regenerate project files* below and close the *Preferences window*.
5. Close Visual Studio.
6. Double click on any of you scripts in Unity to open up Visual Studio again with your scripts.
7. You should see your script in Visual Studio opened up with the .csproj files setup for your Unity Project's Solution in the Solution Explorer panel (if you have it open), with the whole project open in Project mode. Go through your *Assembly-CSharp* solution to see your code (typically within Assets).
8. Open the Error List panel, and in the drop down, select *Build + IntelliSense*.
9. Purposefully make a mistake to see IntelliSense in action producing errors, warnings, and suggestions in the Error List below.
10. **Bonus Step:** If you want to granularize the suggestions in the Error List, change your Code Style settings in Visual Studio in *Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->Code Style* to change how you wish Visual Studio to prefer to act with your code style. You can look through the *C#*, *C#_LSP*, and *All Languages* to make changes to tabbing, formatting, and so on. Up to you. Remember that Unity 20.2.4f1 supports up to C# 7.3 using the Roslyn compiler (so make code style changes and suggestions as appropriately).

Answer (score 0):

We had this issue and after 4 days testing all the possible solutions we found on the internet we tracked down the problem being that the project's file path had the character "%20", after renaming the folder to a name with only letters and numbers both Visual Studio Community and Rider started working properly.